# Animate a floating element to opposite floating points

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I want to be able to click the square at the middle which should slide the top left box to the right horizontally, and the top right box will slide to the bottom vertically, etc.

Duration being 2 seconds for the slide.

http://jsfiddle.net/meD8y/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").click(function(){
        $("#box1, #box3").css("float", "right");
        $("#box2, #box4").css("float", "left");
    });
});
```

not sure how to incorporate the .animate

Comment: try ( http://api.jquery.com/animate/ && || http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp )

Comment: You can't animate changes in float state, you'll likely have to position them absolutely. [This is what happens when you don't](http://jsfiddle.net/meD8y/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The float property cannot be animated. However, you can animate positioning.

Here's a JS Fiddle accomplishing your goal: http://jsfiddle.net/ygP3r/

**HTML**

```
<div id="box-1" class="move"></div>
<div id="box-2"></div>
<div id="box-3" class="move"></div>
<div id="box-4"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: left 2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: left 2s ease;
    -ms-transition: left 2s ease;
    -o-transition: left 2s ease;
}

.move {
    left: calc(100% - 100px);
    left: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
}

#box-1 {
    background-color:red;
}

#box-2 {
    background-color:blue;
}

#box-3 {
    background-color:green;
}

#box-4 {
    background-color:orange;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('div').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('move');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nidhinsg/8wz4Z/)

```
var click_counter = 0;
$("#rotate").click(function() {
    if(click_counter < 4) {
        click_counter++;
    } else {
        click_counter = 1
    }

    switch(click_counter) {
        case 1:
            $("#box1").html("3");
            $("#box1").css("background-color","#999999");
            $("#box2").html("1");
            $("#box2").css("background-color","#ffffff");
            $("#box3").html("4");
            $("#box3").css("background-color","#666666");
            $("#box4").html("2");
            $("#box4").css("background-color","#cccccc");
            break;
        case 2:
            $("#box1").html("2");
            $("#box1").css("background-color","#cccccc");
            $("#box2").html("4");
            $("#box2").css("background-color","#666666");
            $("#box3").html("1");
            $("#box3").css("background-color","#ffffff");
            $("#box4").html("3");
            $("#box4").css("background-color","#999999");
            break;
        case 3:
            $("#box1").html("4");
            $("#box1").css("background-color","#666666");
            $("#box2").html("3");
            $("#box2").css("background-color","#999999");
            $("#box3").html("2");
            $("#box3").css("background-color","#cccccc");    
            $("#box4").html("1");
            $("#box4").css("background-color","#ffffff");
            break;
        case 4:
            $("#box1").html("1");
            $("#box1").css("background-color","#ffffff");
            $("#box2").html("2");
            $("#box2").css("background-color","#cccccc");
            $("#box3").html("3");
            $("#box3").css("background-color","#999999");
            $("#box4").html("4");
            $("#box4").css("background-color","#666666");
            break;
    }
});
```